# MadLib C Program with Redirected Input & Output

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program that accepts a MadLib outline as a .txt file. The program then asks the user for a series of phrases to put into the Madlib. I have this part complete. However, I want to be able to take the user-inputed MadLib phrases & insert them into the .txt file from opened earlier. Then, I want to be able to allow the user to save the completed MadLib under a different .txt file name. The MadLib outline has keywords placed in it that represent where the words entered by the user should go. (see below).

How should I go about replacing these placeholders with the phrases the user enters?

MadLib Outline .txt File:

```
One of the most <adjective> characters in fiction is named
"Tarzan of the <plural-noun>." Tarzan was raised by a/an
<noun> and lives in the <adjective> jungle in the
heart of darkest <place>. He spends most of his time
eating <plural-noun> and swinging from tree to <noun>.
Whenever he gets angry, he beats on his chest and says,
"<funny-noise>!" This is his war cry. Tarzan always dresses in
<adjective> shorts made from the skin of a/an <noun>
and his best friend is a/an <adjective> chimpanzee named
Cheetah. He is supposed to be able to speak to elephants and 
<plural-noun>. In the movies, Tarzan is played by <person's-name>.
```

Comment: You could start by using `fgets` to read a line from your file, and then using `strchr` to find the angle brackets. Then copy the text out and replace the text between the angle brackets with the words you read in. I'm not sure how else to answer your question without just writing a program to do what you're describing. If you have a more specific question, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses fscanf to read from a file. It prompts for each type of word and prints the final text to an output file.  You can supply the filenames as part of the command line as in `program inputfile outputfile`. If file names are not in the command line, default file names of `madlib.txt` will be used for the input file and `madlib-out.txt` will be used for the output file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fpIn = NULL;
    FILE *fpOut = NULL;
    char cFileIn[100] = { 0};
    char cFileOut[100] = { 0};
    char cIn[500] = { 0};
    char cType[100] = { 0};
    char cWord[100] = { 0};
    char cCh[2] = { 0};
    char *pDash = NULL;

    if ( argc == 3) { // use command line arguments if present
        strcpy ( cFileIn, argv[1]);
        strcpy ( cFileOut, argv[2]);
    }
    else { // default file names
        strcpy ( cFileIn, "madlib.txt");
        strcpy ( cFileOut, "madlib-out.txt");
    }


    fpIn = fopen ( cFileIn, "r");
    if ( fpIn == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open input file %s\n", cFileIn);
        return 1; // fopen failed
    }

    fpOut = fopen ( cFileOut, "w");
    if ( fpOut == NULL) {
        fclose ( fpIn); // close the input file
        printf ( "could not open output file %s\n", cFileOut);
        return 1; // fopen failed
    }

    // scan up to 499 characters stopping at <
    while ( fscanf ( fpIn, "%499[^<]", cIn) == 1) {
        // scan one character, should be the <
        if ( ( fscanf ( fpIn, "%1s", cCh)) == 1) {
            if ( cCh[0] == '<') {
                fprintf ( fpOut, "%s", cIn); // print to the output file
                // scan the type of word needed
                if ( ( fscanf ( fpIn, "%99[^>]", cType)) == 1) {
                    if ( ( pDash = strstr ( cType, "-"))) {
                        *pDash = ' '; // remove - if present
                    }
                    // for each type, prompt and scan
                    printf ( "Enter a(n) %s\n", cType);
                    // skip whitespace then scan up to 99 characters stopping at newline
                    scanf ( " %99[^\n]", cWord);
                    fprintf ( fpOut, "%s", cWord); // print to the output file
                }
                if ( ( fscanf ( fpIn, "%1[>]", cCh)) == 1) {
                    ; // scan the >
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose ( fpIn); // close files
    fclose ( fpOut);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you make the prompting for user input more compact by replacing the dash in the `<word1-word2>` (when present) with a space, and then using the modified string in the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative answer which just does find and replace (because writing a parser which does not break on dodgy input is *hard*).

It reads in values from the user, uses the `strstr` function to find the relevant tag in the text and substitutes the user value (repeatedly if the tag appears more than once).  The substitution involves:

1. Keeping everything before the tag.
2. Copying what is after the tag to another string.
3. Inserting the user value.
4. Copying back the contents of the other string.

Code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 65535
#define MAXSTR 100 

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    char string_dict[4][3][MAXSTR]  = 
         { {"What is your name? ", "[name]", ""},
           {"What country do you live in? ", "[country]", ""},
           {"What is your age? ", "[age]", ""},
           {"What is your favourite food?", "[favourite food]", ""} };
    int arr_len = sizeof(string_dict)/sizeof(*string_dict);

    char buf1[BUFSIZE];
    char buf2[BUFSIZE];
    char currtag[MAXSTR];
    char *pos = buf1;
    FILE *fd;
    int i;  

    buf2[0] = '\0';

    fd = fopen("input_file.txt", "r");
    fread(buf1, BUFSIZE-1, 1, fd); 
    fclose(fd);

    for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
        printf("%s", string_dict[i][0]);
        fgets(string_dict[i][2], MAXSTR, stdin);
        string_dict[i][2][strlen(string_dict[i][2])-1] = '\0';
        while (pos = strstr(buf1, string_dict[i][1])) {
            *pos = '\0';
            strcat(buf2, pos + strlen(string_dict[i][1]));
            strcat(pos, string_dict[i][2]);
            pos += strlen(string_dict[i][2]);
            strcat(pos, buf2);
            pos = buf1; 
            buf2[0] = '\0';
        }

    } 

    fd = fopen("output_file.txt", "w");
    fputs(buf1, fd);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

This is pretty robust, but certainly not foolproof.  Question: what happens if you enter the string `[name]` when prompted for your name?  Also, you can exceed the input buffer pretty easily.

`input_file.txt` looks like:

```
My name is [name], and I am [age] years old.  
I live in [country] and my favourite nosh 
is [favourite food].
```

Answer (score 0):

And since there are real answers already, just a quick additional one to point out that if you have a choice, you could do it more easily if you didn't use C.  Python would make it trivial...

```
infile = open("input_file.txt", "r")
template = infile.read()
infile.close()

questions = [ ["What is your name? ", "[name]"],
              ["How old are you? ", "[age]"],
              ["Which country are you from? ", "[country]"],
              ["What is your favourite food? ", "[favourite food]" ] ]

for q in questions:
    template = template.replace(q[1], input(q[0]))

outfile = open("output_file.txt", "w")
outfile.write(template)
outfile.close
```

But maybe you have no choice.